# Querying a collection from ObjectId's with $ne and $or condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I need to serve an unanswered (by user) question to the user where user model holds the questions asked in past with an array, say it `user.asked`.

I want to clarify that I promisified `mongoose` library, hence I'm using those functions, nothing fancy.

User model:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    :
    asked: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Question' }]
})
```

Here's what I tried so far:

```
Question.findAsync({
    _id: {
        $ne: {
            $or: req.user.asked
        }
    }
})
```

which results: `Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"[object Object]\" at path \"_id\"`.

---

I also tried to make an aggregation (example given):

```
{
    $match: {
        _id: {
            $ne: {
                $or: [ ObjectId("56ccfb048f896e0c2d06d08f"), ObjectId("56ccfb048f896e0c2d06d98f") ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

however this returns all of the documents in the collection (even the referred ones).

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`$nin`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/#op._S_nin) operator to find a doc with a field that matches none of the values in an array:

```
Question.findAsync({
    _id: { 
        $nin: [ObjectId("56ccfb048f896e0c2d06d08f"), ObjectId("56ccfb048f896e0c2d06d98f")]
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your brief, yet descriptive answer.